# Angular 2 typescript d3 type issue: Property 'x' does not exist on type '[number, number]'

Tags: angular, d3.js, typescript

I am generating a line chart with d3. It works, but typescript code complain about a property not exists in vs.

> Property 'x' does not exist on type '[number, number]'

[image]

Looking at the error.  It seems like the data point expected is an array with two numbers.

But I am passing in an object.  D3 should support both I think.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error without changing my data?

Comment: how does your data look?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is the solution.  I need to use generics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: hmmm you were missing datatype. good. accept your answer and  +1 from my side :)

Comment: export type DataType = { x: any, y: any }               var line = d3.line<DataType>()

Answer (score 5):

As said, it's a TypeScript interpretation issue. I simply fixed it using brackets notation to access the property. Just like this:

```
let line = d3.line()
  .x(function (d) {
    return x(d['date']);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    return y(d['temp']);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

its a typescript error.

i think there is no x property right now in your d. can you try this

```
 return this.xScale(d?.x);
 return this.xScale(d?.y);
```

or may be your d have data like this `["x_value","y_value"]` in number format.

in this case you should try

```
return this.xScale(d[0]);
return this.yScale(d[1]);
```

i hope this will help

Comment: This is the type definition:

        export function line(): Line<[number, number]>;

        export function line<Datum>(): Line<Datum>;

         https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3-shape/index.d.ts

I am trying to figure out the correct usage for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is use Typescript Optional operator ( ? ).

```
function buildName(firstName: string, lastName?: string) {
    if (lastName)
        return firenter code herestName + " " + lastName;
    else
        return firstName;
}

let result1 = buildName("Bob");                  // works correctly now
let result2 = buildName("Bob", "Adams", "Sr."); // error, too many parameters
let result3 = buildName("Bob", "Adams");    // ah, just right
```

For more details https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Comment: Worth mentioning (took me a bit to puzzle through): passing a standalone function allows you to assign type while it appears you can't assign types in arrow functions. That made this answer work better for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

When data is passed as a variable, defining that data as type `any` should appease TypeScript, e.g.:

```
// Append a 'text' SVGElement with data-driven text() to each 'g' SVGElement 
d3.selectAll('g')
  .each(function(d: any) {
    d3.select(this)
      .append('text')
      .text(d.mytext);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

.x((d:any) => this.xScale(d.x))
.y((d:any) => this.yScale(d.y))