# d3 sunburst chart - getting "TS2339 : Property does not exist on type " error in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to create a `d3-sunburst` chart in `Angular 5` in `TypeScript`,

here is the code snippets,

**json data**

```
var nodeData = {
      "name": "Root", "children": [{
        "name": "Section 1",
        "children": [{ "name": "sec1_child_1", "size": 1 }, { "name": "sec1_child_2", "size": 2 }]
      }, {
        "name": "Section 2",
        "children": [{ "name": "sec2_child_1", "size": 1 }, { "name": "sec2_child_2", "size": 1 }, {"name": "sec2_child_3", "size": 2}]
      }]
    };
```

**javascript's part**

```
   ...
   ...    
   // finding our root node from nodeData
        var root = d3.hierarchy(nodeData)
          .sum((d) => { return d.size }) //sum() iterates through each node in our data and adds a "value" attribute to each one(hear it is "size").
   ...
   ...
      var arc = d3.arc()
          .startAngle((d) => { return d.x0 })
          .endAngle((d) => { return d.x1 })
          .innerRadius((d) => { return d.y0 })
          .outerRadius((d) => { return d.y1 })
   ...
   ...
```

The problem I am facing is, when it serves via `ng serve` / compiles, I am getting the errors as below,

> error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type '{ "
>
> error TS2339: Property 'x0' does not exist on type 'DefaultArcObject'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'x1' does not exist on type 'DefaultArcObject'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'y0' does not exist on type 'DefaultArcObject'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'y1' does not exist on type 'DefaultArcObject'.

Its rendering the d3 chart, even if the error prints,
But, as `TypeScript` is a super set, should it be handled valid `JavaScript` without errors?

seen similar questions in many forums but didn't get a solution yet. Is there any way to avoid this error or at least to suppress?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @VikramDeshmukh Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905301/angular-2-typescript-d3-type-issue-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-number